# Standard API to find the current Activity in foreground and the focused view in it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bluetooth, android-activitymanager

So I have this Bluetooth device which pairs with a regular Android device and sends out some form of Bluetooth commands. Basically it sends out a long byte sequence which is then encoded to a regular string and displayed on currently focused editable field of what ever application is in foreground.

I am wondering how this is being done. The Bluetooth device does not have any companion Application and all it does is send a Bluetooth command.Is there a standard API somewhere to do this. I am guessing there is else there is no way to achieve the stuff I am seeing

Comment: It is probably just serving as a Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well that makes sense. Would you be able to describe it a bit more in details or provide some links.

Comment: Um, Bluetooth keyboards have been around for a decade or so. Android has supported them for 5+ years. If you want details about your hardware, contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. I dug down a bit and came across articles explaining how to develop custom accessories for Android devices. I think that's what I was looking for